# what this function do please ? (java)

Tags: java

```
    public static int ABC(int x, int y)
{
    if(y==0)
        return(1);
    else
        return(x * ABC(x,y-1));
}
```

what this function do please ? factorial ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `x` is never changed and multiplied to the 1 exactly `y` times, as y is decremented in each recursive call until it is 0. So the function computes `x^y` in a recursive way.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like x ^ y